# Key names can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]" (unbound names start with "$")

Tags: firebase, firebase-database

Всем добрый день, решил обновить правила безопасности своей Realtime Database в Firebase

Использую правила из офф.документации но.. получаю ошибки, одну связанную с " , " поправил, а вот другая весьма странная и моих знаний не достаточно. (( И вообще не понятно, можно ли верить в таком случае офф.документации ? ))

Код:

```
{
"rules": {
"some_path/${uid}": {
  ".read": true,
  ".write": "request.auth.uid == uid"
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Может быть ошибка здесь? `"some_path/${uid}"` и нужно заменить на: `"some_path/$uid"`

Comment: Увы, не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка не из-за запятой а из-за того, что написано

```
  ".read": true,
```

Должно быть:

```
  ".read":"true",
```